# How do I repeat a command until successful? Not working as intended

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to implement a retry loop in Bash and it's not working the way I intended. I'm trying to repeat a command until it's successful.

When the command successfully completes, it contains the string/text "100.00%|" followed by a long text-based progress bar in the Terminal/console. In this case, I only care about the "100.00%" portion, and not the other stuff that comes after it (no space).

In other words, only the first seven characters of the "longer string". The command has been tested and works on single-iteration runs. Here's a snippet of how I'm implementing the code.

```
while ! "100.00%"
do
    Run command
    sleep 2
done
```

But couple things happen when I run the script. While it successfully continues to repeat itself on failed attempts, I keep getting the following error message.

```
./Script.sh: line 27: 100.00%: command not found
```

On top of that, looks like it continues to repeat itself even after successfully running the command and the string-snippet "100.00%" appears in the Terminal, which indicates something could be wrong with my syntax or logic. Is it not detecting the correct string? Am I missing something else in my loop? Could something be wrong with my syntax?

If "100.00%" appears in the console, by the logic, shouldn't it exit the loop and continue the script? How do I solve these issues?

Comment: `while [ "$(command)" != "100.00%" ]; do ...` (use *command substitution* to compare the results of `command` to `"100.00%"` using a string comparison)

Comment: @jcchong9 : Wouldn't it be more idiomatic to have the command signal success by returning exit code `0`, and use something like `until Run command; do sleep 2; done`, instead of doing a string comparision?

Comment: The thing that goes after `while` needs to be a command (or series of commands), so it tries to run `"100.00%"` as a command, and it isn't one, so that always fails. You need something that searches the output of the command, or maybe... does the command exit with a failure status code if it doesn't work (which is what it should do), and with success if it succeeds (ditto)? If it does that, you can use the command itself as the `while !` (or `until`) condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
Run command
while [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
do
    Run command
    sleep 2
done
```

Answer (score 1):

run command until succeeds but with 2 seconds to retry

```
while ! Run command
do
    sleep 2
done
```

see more detals:https://www.networkworld.com/article/3541298/how-to-repeat-a-linux-command-until-it-succeeds.html